# How would I find the total resistance of the following circuit?

Tags: resistors, circuit-analysis

I tried finding the total resistance but my answer isn't correct. The answer is supposed to be 6.66 kΩ.

[image]

Comment: Start reducing the series and paralleled values one by one, hint (start with R5,R6)

Comment: If you want any more help that what has been offered, show some effort. We are not here to do *your* homework for *you* - that's *your* job.

Comment: It's your homework, actually an easy one, and i am sure you can and will make it. To check your result, try assembling the circuit and measuring it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case whenever you are calculating the circuit resistance you want the total resistance seen by your only voltage source (18 V battery)

you better start from the node C,
Such that i can see a 1 KΩ series with another 1 KΩ
[image]

The equivalent resistance of this combination is a 2 KΩ resistance
so your circuit now looks like this

[image]

i can see now a 2.2 KΩ (Node B) parallel to a 2 KΩ  (Node C)
    [image: enter code here]

We can now simply estimate the equivalent resistance of this combination which should be equals to

[image]

Now we place this resistance at node (B) and remove the node (C) branch (Open circuit) or vice verse

Such that your new circuit will look like this

[image]

Now i can see a 22/21 KΩ Series with a 1 KΩ  resistance

Such that they are combined into a new resistance of value 43/21 KΩ

Your circuit will look something like this

[image]

Now this circuit can be easily solved 
you have a 43/21 KΩ  parallel with a 2.2 KΩ
and this whole combination equivalent resistance is series with the 5.6 KΩ  resistance

Answer (score 6):

Assuming total resistance means the resistance seen by the 18 volt battery, then the procedure is to successively use the formulas for series and parallel resistors. First find the series result of R5 and R6.  That resistance is then in parallel with R4.  That result is in series with R3.  Again, the result of that is in parallel with R2.  Finally this result is in series with R1. If you do the arithmetic correctly, you will get the correct result.